# C++ Variable Scope Issues

Tags: c++, scope, compiler-errors

I'm trying to implement a singly linked list in c++ and I'm running into a lot of scope issues and I'm not sure why. I'm getting errors like `LinkedList.cpp:28:11: error: ‘class LinkedList’ has no member named ‘current’ if(this->current == NULL)`

Here's my .h file

```
#ifndef LINKEDLIST_H
#define LINKEDLIST_H

class Node
{
    friend class LinkedList;
private:
    int data;
    Node* next;
    Node* getNext() { return this->next; };
public:
    Node() { data = 0; next = NULL; };
    void setData(int data) { this->data = data; };
    void setNext(Node* next) { this->next = next; };
};

class LinkedList
{
private:
    Node* head;
    Node* current;
public:
    LinkedList() { head = current = NULL; };
    //LinkedList(const LinkedList &l)
    //TO DO: Destructor
    void next();
    void reset();
    void append(int data);
    void replaceData(int data);
    void removeNode(int data);
    void removeLast();
    bool reset();
    void operator++() { next(); };
};

#endif
```

and here is my cpp file (There my be more issues, especially with the implementation of the LinkedList, but I'm more concerned with the current compilation errors)

```
#include "LinkedList.h"
#include <stddef.h>

void LinkedList::next()
{
    if(current != NULL)
    {
        current = current->next;
    }
}

void LinkedList::reset()
{
    if(head != NULL)
    {
        current = head;
    }
}

void LinkedList::append(int data)
{
    Node* newNode = new Node();
    newNode->setData(data);
    newNode->setNext(NULL);

    reset();

    if(this->current == NULL)
    {
        this->head = newNode;
    }

    else
    {
        while(this->current->getNext() != NULL)
        {
            this->current = this->current->getNext();
        }
        this->current->setNext(newNode);
    }
}

void LinkedList::removeNode(int data)
{
    this->current = this->head;

    if(this->current == NULL) return;

    if(this->current->getNext() == NULL)
    {
        delete this->current;
        this->head = NULL;
    }

    else
    {
        Node* previous;
        do
        {
            if(this->current->getData() == data) break;
            previous = this->current;
            this->current = this->current->getNext();
        } while(this->current != NULL);

        previous->setNext(this->current->getNext());

        delete this->current;
    }
}

void LinkedList::removeLast()
{
    this->current = this->head;

    while(this->current->getNext() != NULL)
    {
        this->current = this->current->getNext();
    }

    delete this->current;
}
```

I realize I'm more than likely missing something so incredibly obvious, but I cannot figure this out to save my life.

Comment: Where is the piece of code that causes the error located? Looks like another `LinkedList` is being used, without a `current` member.

Comment: From the header file, the class `LinkedList` clearly *has* a member `current`, so something else is going on. Did you include the header? Or use some forward-declaration? Do you have a LinkedList somewhere else? How does your cpp look like?

Comment: @iksemyonov The reference to current in the if statement is where that error occurs

Comment: @Anedar my cpp file is a bit long should I post the whole thing? Every time I reference head and current I'm getting the same error telling me it's not a member of LinkedList

Comment: @John then do post, there is no other way to help you. As far as my question goes, it's about the location of the snippet relative to the entire codebase, not the line relative to the snippet.

Comment: @pm100 The first line it fails at is 4, saying the method next() isn't a member function of LinkedList

Comment: aha - so there are *lots* of compile errors. Shows us some more. It smells like you are not using the header you think you are. Just put 'fiddly foo' in the header and see if the compiler complains

Comment: May simply be the wrong header included..

Comment: It might be my makefile that's wrong then because there were no issues when I typed random gibberish into the header file. I have LinkedList.o dependent on LinkedList.h and LinkedList.cpp, so I'm going to guess my dependencies are wrong there

Comment: @pm100 I'm using gcc and I tried compiling with g++ -c LinkedList.cpp -o LinkedList.o and I still got errors. Is that the correct command for compiling? I'm trying to find out if it's my makefile or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void reset();
bool reset();
```

function cannot be overloaded by return type.

```
void LinkedList::removeNode(int data)
{
    if (this->current->getData() == data) break;
}
```

Your `node` class doesn't have a `getData()` function.

I've successfully compiled your code by fixing those 2 issues [Live Demo](http://ideone.com/ggaJSn).

If that isn't enough, then perhaps you are probably not including the LinkedList header at all.

Comment: I'm still getting a ton of errors, so it must be my makefile that's wrong. I have LinkedList.o dependent on LinkedList.h and LinkedList.cpp. I'm guessing that's incorrect

Comment: I have the include statement at the top of my cpp file, is there any other way to verify if I'm including properly?